# Simple_form Error - undefined method `model_name' for ActiveRecord::Relation:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I am trying to add some more conditional logic to my edit action by passing params into a where.

Whenever I use anything other than .find(params[:id], the error undefined method `model_name' for ActiveRecord::Relation:Class

My code is below

Controller:

```
def edit
   @office = Office.where("id = ? AND company_id = ?", params[:id], @company.id )
end
```

View:

```
<%= simple_form_for @office, :url => settings_office_path, :html => { :class => "office_form" } do |f| %>
  <h1>Edit <%= @office.office_name %> Details</h1>
  <%= render :partial => 'form', :locals => { :f => f } %>
<% end %>
```

I outputted the class for @office which is ActiveRecord::Relation.  If I just use

```
@office = Office.find(params[:id])
```

the output is Office.

I think this is the problem but don't know how to fix it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The form expects a single record to be in the `@office` instance variable, the `where`-method doesn't return a single record but a relation, which can be multiple records, once queried.

The correct way is:

```
@office = Office.where(:company_id => @company.id).find(params[:id])
```

Or even better, if you've defined the relation:

```
@office = @company.offices.find(params[:id])
```

Comment: Great, they work!  The second one is nice and clean so I have used that.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Great explanation - you didn't just provide code that answered the question, you also explained WHY it works the way it does. Very helpful!

Answer (score 4):

I also had the same issue I fixed it by using `.first`.

Similar to this one :

```
def edit
   @office = Office.where("id = ? AND company_id = ?", params[:id], @company.id ).first
end
```